# Is heapq.merge() supposed to return a minheap in Python 3.8, and if not, why does it sometimes appear to do so?

Tags: python-3.8

I was told this code would return me a minheap, but after staring at my screen for 10 minutes i have concluded that this isnt a min heap, so why?

import heapq

L1 = [3,32,423,4,5,6,]
L2 = [32,66,6,32,4,8,0,]

L3 = heapq.merge(L1, L2)
print(L3)
print(list(L3))

> > > [3, 32, 32, 66, 6, 32, 4, 8, 0, 423, 4, 5, 6]
> > > if this is a minheap then explain to me why, thank in advance :)

a min heap is what i expected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`heapq.merge` *uses* heap for implementation of merging two *sorted lists* into one *sorted list*. It does not take arbitrary lists as input, nor does it produce a heap.

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge):

> ```
> heapq.merge(*iterables, key=None, reverse=False)
> ```
>
> Merge multiple sorted inputs into a single sorted output (for example,
> merge timestamped entries from multiple log files). Returns an
> iterator over the sorted values.